# How to refresh PartialView by calling ActionLink in Grid in PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a PartialView, that contains grid. The grid has a list of files that can be deleted. After user deletes the file I return PartialView with new file list. 
Issue: 
The new screen contains ONLY the PartialView. The MenuItems and all other things on the page are NOT rendered. 
Any help highly appreciated. Thank you...

MY code:
**Sellers.cshtml**

'ACSDemoWinAzureACS.Models.SellersModel

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="gridContainer">
     @Html.Partial("_AdminView", Model)
</div>
```

'
**_AdminView.cshtml - The PartialView**

```
@model ACSDemoWinAzureACS.Models.HomeModel
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="gridMain">

@using (Html.BeginForm("Admin", "Home", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    foreach(var file in Model.files)
    {
       <tr>
         <td><a href="@file.FilePath" Target="_blank"> @file.FileName</a></td>
         <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete" , "Delete" , "Home", 
                                                 new  { id = file.FileName },
                                                 new AjaxOptions
             {
                 UpdateTargetId="gridMain", // <-- DOM element ID to update
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, // <-- Replace the content of DOM element
                 HttpMethod = "GET" // <-- HTTP method
             })

          </td>
        </tr>
    }
  }

 </div>
```

**HOmeController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult Delete(string id)  
        {
             _model.Delete(id);                
              _model.files = _model.GetFiles();
             return PartialView("_AdminView",_model);
        }
```

Comment: The issue that you have with only the partial view rendered is due to the fact that your `Delete` method is returning `PartialView`. The result of that is exactly what you see - the `_Layout` page is not loaded. Sometimes this is desired, in your case it seem you need to return `JSONResult` and relay much more on JS/jQuery.

Comment: And in your case if the main View - `Sellers.cshtml` is just one partial view you can `return View("Seller")` in your delete method and render the whole page again which will work until you manage to rewrite your code properly to use AJAX and JSON. Or I think there was an option to explicitly say if and what layout to be rendered when you make AJAX calls like this. I don't have time now but look for `IsAjaxRequest` and how it's used, maybe this will help too. GL.

Comment: Thank you Leron for your help. Now I get the problem.